# three fair six-sided dice are thrown and the dice show three different numbers. find the probability that at least one six is obtained??

Tags: probability

I got 91/216 using binomial distribution. I found the probability using how to find no six was obtained and subtracted from 1.

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

The probability you found is indeed the probability of a six being rolled if you rolled 3 dices but neglected the condition that dice shows three different numbers. You can explicitly work it out or use some result about conditional probability.